# OS X installer booting instead of Macintosh HD

Tags: macbook-pro, install

Accidentally closed MacBook Pro while installing El Capitan. Now only bootable disks are my bootcamp, Recovery, and OS X installer. Macintosh HD shows up in Disk Utility and I've tried repairing it, no errors. On the properties it shows that it isn't bootable, that's it.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just erase the partition and start over?

Comment: recently got some data that I do not have a backup for. I can erase it, just not ideal so was wondering if there is a way around doing so.

Comment: So you were upgrading to El Cap from a previously-functioning OS?

Comment: yes, everything was working fine

Answer (score 1):

Just install the system again: it shouldn't overwrite any files outside of the system.

Comment: are you sure? it looks awfully like it would be a fresh install... doesn't say so though.

Comment: If you're feeling unsure, boot into the installer, open disk utility, and image the disk to some other external volume. If anything goes wrong, you have a copy.

Comment: it says there is not enough space on the disk. any suggestions? I'm assuming there's no way to delete stuff on the disk from the situation we are in right now.

Comment: @PravarKapoor you could put the OSX installer on a USB

Comment: @PravaKapoor I believe you can access a terminal and remove files from there, I'll check later. Remind me in about 12 hour if I forget.

Comment: @PravarKapoor Yes, you can indeed. [Here's a list of stuff you can do in Terminal.](http://www.howtogeek.com/189575/8-mac-system-features-you-can-access-in-recovery-mode/)